# Альтернатива autolayout constraints

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Пришло в голову использовать два разных `.xib` для двух размеров экранов `iPhone` как альтернативу `autolayout constraints` которые очень функциональны но несколько неудобны в использовании. Данное решение кажется довольно простым и легким, но может существуют еще альтернативы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Альтернатив как таковых нет, сам дико плююсь от autolayout'а, но это просто потому что еще не осилил его.

Все новшества которые вводит эппл довольно хороши собой, но приходится тратить массу времени на то, чтобы понять и изучить тот или иной инструмент.

Ну и как всегда - серебряной пули не существует, те или иные вещи имеют свои плюсы и минусы.

ИМХО, нужно просто пробовать все эти вещи, а уже потом, набравшись опыта и насобирав граблей, выбирать нужный инструмент для конкретной задачи.

И да, вы все еще можете попробовать делать все из кода, но это очень трудоемкий процесс, который требует огромных усилий по поддержке, гораздо дешевле посмотреть пару-тройку видео с WWDC и научиться делать ровно.

**P.S.** *простите за импульсивность, не в духе...*

Answer (score 0):

Вот книжка на Русском https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3ZjLaCb8KKkaW43WGRkX04zVms/edit?pli=1 Учи пока не появиться более удобный способ))))) Удачи!!!

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива есть - выключайте autolayout и выставляйте autoresizing masks...
Сам отказался от autoresizing masks, но переход был был достаточно болезненный. В итоге работать с autolayout гораздо проще и быстрее: легко настраивается необходимое поведение при ресайсах, base localization, но есть и минусы типа ужасно муторной работы с анимациями, нельзя просто взять что-то и передвинуть, приходится создавать IBOutlet для нужных UILayoutConstraints.

Answer (score -1):

Откажитесь от storyboard и xib. Пишите интерфейс кодом. Более унылого Гов*&а я не видел по работе с интерфейсами. Жалкое подобие Flex билдера и темболее WPF. 
Сейчас мы пишем интерфейс руками и ни чем не ограничены в действиях. 
И мы задавались таким же вопросом, как что и зачем? И было решено в Аналы Фруктов эти билдеры интерфейсов.
Сейчас мы просто знаем размеры экрана, хоть будь это бабушкин телевизор, и под него ресайзем красиво с анимацией ввсе всюхи.

Comment: Это самый хреновый совет который я когда-либо слышал.

Безусловно, код дает больше возможностей чем чистый IB, но IB + код дает все те же возможности + меньше кода, и это проще саппортить.

Мне приходилось переводить все эти ручные лэйауты на XIB'ы, выходило на порядок меньше кода, из почти 1000 строк оставалось меньше 300. 

Чем меньше писать руками, тем проще саппортить.

Надеюсь вы еще измените свое мнение в сторону более удобных средств для работы с интерфейсами.

Comment: >Надеюсь вы еще измените свое мнение в сторону более удобных средств для работы с интерфейсами.
Только после того когда эти инструменты будут действительно удобными.

Comment: Все относительно, мне было мучительно больно и _неудобно_ поддерживать проект, в котором вообще все было написано из кода, даже статические лэйблы, которые никогда не изменяются.

Был реальный проект (а думаю что и не один) в котором все контроллеры были под тысячу строк размером, и б**о**льшая часть этих строк - лэйаут.

Это действительно тяжело.

Comment: Да, возмножно, но как показала практика, хоршо структурированный код решает эту проблему.

Comment: Вот, видно, что существуют два лагеря: сторонников и противников подхода, при котором все делается руками. Лично я в данном вопросе целиком и полностью на стороне Bimawa, могу подписаться под его ответом и каждым его комментарием: 1) жалкое подобие FB 2) пассаж про бабушкин телевизор 3) "когда инструменты будут действительно удобными..." и самое главное! про 4) хорошо структурированный код.

Comment: Но добавлю также, что полностью во всем согласен и с @AlexDenisov, и что сам мечтаю действительно добраться до соответствующих WWDC и разобраться во всех тонкостях, но уж точно не в середине большого проекта, в котором почти с самого начала делаю все исключительно кодом и руками!

Comment: Случай из жизни: " проект весь строился на сторибоардах, было всего 10 экранов, и в один прекрассный день Xcode крашился при попытке открыть storyboard для редактирования. Я очень долго думал что за чертовщина? Но после мучительных отладочных манипуляций, выяснилось что не хватает Оперативной памяти. Пришлось пользоваться Sublime Text редактором и править storyboard файлики руками. А это означало изучить всю структуры XML боардов и запомнить идентификаторы объектов."  В итоге после сдачи проекта, было решено пересоздать весь проект с нуля и полностью на коде.

Comment: Золотая середина, господа! То что можно и просто - IB, то что нельзя или непросто в IB - руками.